# A banned perspective about banning based on score from a banned user banned from asking about bans

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, post-ban

Alright, I'm sorry if this title was confusing, but I couldn't resist the urge to make the title a gag ;)

Right now I'm pretty sure that the **maximum** score for a ban from asking questions is around -3, and the total number of questions is around 12. Now, I have some problems with this. I would like to quote the help section article about question asking privilege loss.

> If a user cannot demonstrate, after asking a reasonable number of questions, that their contributions are making the site better (or at very least, not making it worse) then they will be blocked from asking further questions until they have demonstrated their ability to contribute positively.

Basically, a user would have to actively making negative contributions in order to get banned, right? Wrong. I can think of so many scenarios where this isn't true. Here are a few:

> A user posts many questions, 3 of which get one downvote each, the rest received no downvotes or upvotes.

This isn't necessarily "making the site worse", as said in the help section, it's just not improving it much. And as said in the above quote, not actively making the site worse shouldn't be enough to block a user.

> A user posts several questions, some of which get one or two upvotes, others get none, and one of them gets a large amount of downvotes (10, for example).

As said many times, one question shouldn't be enough to ban a user. But in this case, it would be.

Should we lower the maximum total score (sorry again if this is a confusing way to say it) so that users aren't unfairly banned (maybe to -5 or -6)? If not, what can we change that will help make the ban selection more accurate so that users aren't unfairly banned?

**UPDATE:** I just had the ban lifted, although by not very much. I'm going to wait for more upvotes before I take a risk at asking another question. Thank you guys so much for helping me and giving me the feedback necessary to gain some upvotes.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back up your numbers? The details of the question ban algorithm are very deliberately kept hidden to avoid people gaming the system. And remember that deleted questions count too.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I'm not 100% on the numbers, but when I got banned from asking questions, that's what the numbers were.

Comment: A) your experience is anecdotal. Kinda hard to make sense of a deliberately hidden algorithm (the whole point of hiding it is to make sure ppl don't game it, I'd be surprised if you 'cracked it'). B) 12 questions with no upvotes is.... A lot of cruft when you think about it. Definitely not helping the site, and too many of those and you end up in a wasteland of 'meh'. Not necessarily the same experience stack has been trying to go for :/. If that puts you on the very verge of the ban where 1-2 upvotes kick you out? I'm.... Not sure I'm against it

Comment: @Patrice see what the help center said above. Not helping the site isn't ground for banning, so therefor "meh" should technically safe.

Comment: @Lemmy I'm not certain lawyering about the specifics here ('technically safe?'). Honestly if at 12 questions you have nothing with even a +1, and a track of -3, I'd say chances are the next question is of the same nature. Eventually, yes that hurts the site. It has to stop somewhere. The limit doesn't seem too far fetched, if it's the one you paint (if you ask me). But at the same time, its impossible to really know, cause there are waaaaay too many unknowns here

Comment: @Patrice your right, but it's pretty hard to get upvotes on a question if you're bad at coding like I do :(

Comment: The wording reflects the policy, it's not a legislated regulation you can pedantically say isn't being met but is required to be, moreover with your interpretation of its terms. Why not try as hard as you can to find out what were the bad & good aspects of your ill- & well-received posts? PS Bad at coding does not imply bad at asking. Bad at following tons of asking advice makes bad questions.

Comment: You are not banned from asking about bans.

Comment: @Lemmy not at all. If you wanna take the 'poor little me' route... It won't get you more points here...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are making a lot of assumptions here about how, precisely, the question-ban algorithm works. Unfortunately, none of those assumptions are justified. The details on how it works are intentionally kept secret and not disclosed to the public. Even moderators are not privy to most of the details.

However, what we *do* know is that one question is not enough to get you question-banned, and it isn't enough to do so in your examples, either. You claim in comments that those were the numbers when you got banned from asking questions, but…they weren't, unless you previously had a different account.

Anyway, the question-ban algorithm operates on a **total quality score**. I think that's the best way for it to operate. If your contributions to the site are an overall, (mostly) net positive, then you should be allowed to continue to contribute. Otherwise, we limit (throttle) your number of contributions. The logic is that you are taking more than you are giving. It takes time for people to read and answer your questions, and if the questions are not a significant, useful contribution to the knowledge base that we're building, then you're taking more than you're giving. Furthermore, poorly-asked or low-quality questions take more time to moderate (edit, close, etc.), so this takes *even more time and attention* from the community.

Currently, your account is blocked from asking questions. However, you have no questions with a large number of downvotes. (You also have no deleted questions.) You have three questions with a score of −1, and the rest all have scores of 0. That's a *very* troubling pattern. You haven't asked *a single question* that was deemed worthy of an upvote by the community. I have no objections whatsoever to throttling back your ability to ask questions until you can improve your asking skills.

> but it's pretty hard to get upvotes on a question if you're bad at coding like I do :(

No, it isn't. Not at all. Asking a good question has almost nothing to do with your coding skill. Plenty of beginner programmers have asked high-quality questions that are well-received by our community and been extremely useful to others with the same question.

Comment: But most of my questions are high quality, with no grammar or spelling errors, and I define what I want answered. In fact, I wrote them following the guidelines of how to write a good question. So the questions either aren't getting enough attention or are just misunderstood. I've edited every one of those questions, yet no change. I'm starting to wonder if it's even worth posting here if people are going to treat my questions like a plague. Go ahead and look at my questions, you'll see that almost all of them are written considerably well.

Comment: @LemmyX Being "well written" isn't a sufficient condition to being a good question. As a small tip to get you started, are you entirely sure that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61664425/text-aligncenter-not-aligning-buttons-in-nav-section) contains a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Users should not be required to visit your site to reproduce it, all the necessary details should be in the question itself.

Comment: [*cough, cough*](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/885476/am-i-quality-banned-for-questions) ...

Comment: @rene That formula doesn’t cover the criteria, I’m afraid. I don’t know what the criteria *are* but I can find accounts that are not question banned while your query claims they would be and vice versa. Sorry.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it is a guestimate, a ball park figure. But you're right that it doesn't cover all criteria. I'm only told these are the most contributing factors.

Comment: The only relevant factor is a low overall quality score, evidence that someone is not contributing in a significant or meaningful way to our collective attempt to build up a knowledge base. Trying to guess and/or game the question-ban algorithm is not productive. I still have *yet* to see a single false-positive.

Comment: @E_net4theclosevoter Yes, I see what you mean. I wasn't really sure how to make it reproducible, since it wasn't a problem that was reproduced in the snippet creator, only on my website.